# Can anyone please tell how $f(x)=x^2$ is neither even nor odd when $0<x<2\pi$??

Tags: complex-analysis

How can $f(x)=x^2$ be neither even nor odd when $0<x<2\,\pi$? I am struggling with this question. Please help me out with this.

Comment: Do you mean $0<x<2\pi$? For formatting tips please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: "Even" and "odd" make sense only if the  domain of the function is symmetric around $0$, that's not so in this case. Here, it's likely that we're speaking of Fourier analysis (because of the interval $(0,2\pi)$), and a periodic continuation of that function is certainly neither odd nor even.

Comment: "Complex analysis" does not mean *analysis which you find complicated*.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean $f(x) = x^2$ defined on the interval $0 < x < 2 \pi$? Or perhaps $\pi e$?

In order for a function to be even or odd, its domain must be symmetric about $0$, i.e. whenever $f(x)$ is defined, $f(-x)$ must also be defined and be either $f(x)$ or $-f(x)$.  Here that is not the case: in order for $f(x)$ to be defined, $x$ must be in the interval $(0, \pi)$, and then $f(-x)$ is not defined.

Comment: Then again, it might be tacitly assumed that "even" and "odd" now apply to the midpoint of the domain rather than 0, in which case $x^2$ is also neither even nor odd.